# How to create buttons that display images?

Tags: android

I created three buttons and each button shows text when it is clicked. Now I need to add to that so the buttons show text + an image. all the texts and images will only appear if the buttons are clicked. For example, when the user clicks on first button, text1 + image1 appears. When the user clicks on second button, text2 + image2 appears in the same places of text1 and image1. Any help please? here are my codes:

XML (I couldn't post the first code part here but below is the most important parts)

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Recipe 1"
    android:id="@+id/click_btn"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/response"
    android:layout_below="@+id/click_btn"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button15"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button15" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Recipe 2"
    android:id="@+id/button15"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Recipe 3"
    android:id="@+id/button16"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/response"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/response" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java:

```
package com.example.android.ch;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static com.example.android.R.*;


public class Recipes extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
TextView resp; ImageView imageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layout.activity_recipes);
    resp = (TextView)this.findViewById(id.response);
    Button b = (Button)this.findViewById(id.click_btn);
    Button c = (Button)this.findViewById(id.button15);
    Button d = (Button)this.findViewById(id.button16);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(id.imageView);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    c.setOnClickListener(this);
    d.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {



    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){

    }
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_recipes, menu);
    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.click_btn: /** on click_btn button click */
            resp.setText("2   medium sweet potatoes (about 1 pound total) \n1/2  teaspoon salt\n1/2  teaspoon ground cumin\n1/2  teaspoon chili powder\n1/2  teaspoon paprika\n1/4  teaspoon ground black pepper");
            break;

        case R.id.button15: /** on button15 button click */
            resp.setText("1 large egg yolk, at room temperature\n1/2 cup extra-virgin olive oil; more for grilling\n2 teaspoons minced fresh flat-leaf parsley\n1 teaspoon minced fresh tarragon\n1 1/2 teaspoons fresh lemon juice; more to taste Kosher salt");
            break;

        case R.id.button16: /** on button16 button click */
            resp.setText("1/2 cup butter, softened\n1 cup packed light brown sugar\n1 1/2 cups all-purpose flour\n3 cups rolled oats\n1 teaspoon ground cinnamon");
            break;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You can use ImageButtons instead. So that you can display an image or text on the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got right answer with many of you and thank you all but I meant to create three buttons and show text+image Not inside the icon. To do that I created three fragments xml files so when the user click on a button it will bring the fragment and place it.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can add image or icon to a button with text.
use below code for this -

```
   <Button
     android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_logout"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Recipe 3"
     android:id="@+id/button16"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

here i have added one more property **android:drawableRight** you can change it to **android:drawableLeft**, **android:drawableTop**, or **android:drawableBottom** and set image on button.

Comment: I'm trying to add text +image not inside the icon.

Comment: can you give a example image, which kind of design you require then it will be more helpfull

Answer (score 1):

Use drawableLeft (or any direction) attribute to display image with text,

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_text"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/button_icon"
    ... />
```

Above code will display image like [image]

Answer (score 0):

include the imageview and textview in a layout and keep it's visibility as invisible/gone.Then on clicking a button(for example button1) inside the onclick listener method you need to try like

```
imageview.setimage("your image");
textview.setText("your text");
```

change this code inside each buttonclick listener with various value.